# grok filter fails for ISO8601 timestamps since 5.2

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

since I've upgraded our ELK-stack from 5.0.2 to 5.2 our grok filters fail and I've no idea why. Maybe I've overlooked something in the changelogs?

**Filter**

```
filter {
  if [type] == "nginx_access" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{IPORHOST:remote_addr} - %{USERNAME:remote_user} \[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] \"%{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}\" %{INT:status} %{INT:body_bytes_sent} %{QS:http_referer} %{QS:http_user_agent} \"%{DATA:host_uri}\" \"%{DATA:proxy}\" \"%{DATA:upstream_addr}\" \"%{WORD:cache_status}\" \[%{NUMBER:request_time}\] \[(?:%{NUMBER:proxy_response_time}|-)\]" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
    }
    mutate {
      convert => {
        "proxy_response_time" => "float"
        "request_time" => "float"
        "body_bytes_sent" => "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
Invalid format: \"2017-02-05T15:55:38+01:00\" is malformed at \"-02-05T15:55:38+01:00\"
```

**Full Error**

```
[2017-02-05T15:55:49,500][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Failed action. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"filebeat-2017.02.05", :_type=>"nginx_access", :_routing=>nil}, 2017-02-05T14:55:38.000Z proxy2 4.3.2.1 - - [2017-02-05T15:55:38+01:00] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Zabbix" "example.com" "host1:10040" "1.2.3.4:10040" "MISS" [0.095] [0.095]], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"filebeat-2017.02.05", "_type"=>"nginx_access", "_id"=>"AVoOxh7p5p68dsalXDFX", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [timestamp]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Invalid format: \"2017-02-05T15:55:38+01:00\" is malformed at \"-02-05T15:55:38+01:00\""}}}}}
```

The whole thing works perfectly on http://grokconstructor.appspot.com and the TIMESTAMP_ISO8601 still seems the right choice (https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns)

**Techstack**

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Elasticsearch 5.2.0
- Logstash 5.2.0
- Filebeat 5.2.0
- Kibana 5.2.0

Any idas?

Cheers,
Finn

**UPDATE**

So this version works for some reason

```
filter {
  if [type] == "nginx_access" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{IPORHOST:remote_addr} - %{USERNAME:remote_user} \[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] \"%{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}\" %{INT:status} %{INT:body_bytes_sent} %{QS:http_referer} %{QS:http_user_agent} \"%{DATA:host_uri}\" \"%{DATA:proxy}\" \"%{DATA:upstream_addr}\" \"%{WORD:cache_status}\" \[%{NUMBER:request_time}\] \[(?:%{NUMBER:proxy_response_time}|-)\]" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
    }
    date {
        match => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" ]
        target => "timestamp"
    }
    mutate {
      convert => {
        "proxy_response_time" => "float"
        "request_time" => "float"
        "body_bytes_sent" => "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If someone can shed some light why I have to redefine a valid ISO8601 date I would be happy to know.

Comment: How does your *timestamp* look like in the actual log?

Comment: As far as I can see, normal ISO8601 format, e.g. 2017-02-06T07:22:31+01:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you specify the [format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/date.html) of `timestamp` you are expecting in your documents, where the mapping could look like:

```
PUT index
{
  "mappings": {
    "your_index_type": {
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type":   "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+01:SS" <-- make sure to give the correct one
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you do not specify it correctly, *Elasticsearch* will expect  the *timestamp* value in format of ISO. **OR** you could do a [date match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-match) for your `timestamp` field, which could look something like this within your *filter*:

```
date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+01:SS" ] <--match the timestamp (I'm not sure what +01:ss stands for, make sure it matches)
    target => "timestamp"
    locale => "en"
    timezone => "UTC"
}
```

Or you could add a new field and match that to the *timestamp* if you wish, and then you could remove it if you aren't really using it, since you have the timestamp on the new field. Hope it helps.

Comment: SS stands hundredths of seconds, so the correct form is

    date {
            match => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" ]
            target => "timestamp"
        }

But for some reason this works, thanks. I've anyone knows why I have to specify the an ISO format again I would be glad to know =)